# Show and Hide function doen't work in JSF

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I'm trying to hide and show my text area in JSF using JQuery. But it doesn't work. Conditions are good, but functions doesn't work.
What's wrong? I'm not newest in JS but I start to explore JSF and here using JS in very strange way.
Here you can see my code below.
thanx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Add new field</title>


</h:head>
<h:body>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">

    </script>

    <h:form>
        <b:commandButton look="link" action="response?faces-redirect=true"
            value="Response" />
        <b:commandButton look="link" action="fields?faces-redirect=true"
            value="Fields" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form style="margin: 0 auto">
        <h3>Adding Form Components</h3>
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:outputLabel id="label" for="label">Label:</h:outputLabel>
            <div>
                <b:inputText binding="#{infoManageBean.labelInput}"
                    placeholder="Name, Country, etc." required="true" id="labelText"
                    value="#{infoManageBean.field.label}">
                </b:inputText>
                <p:message for="labelText" />
                <h:outputText value="#{addFieldValidationBean.label}" />
                <br /> <br />
            </div>
            <h:outputLabel for="type">Type:</h:outputLabel>

            <b:selectOneMenu onchange="handleChange(this.value)" required="true"
                value="#{infoManageBean.field.type}">

                <f:selectItems value="#{fieldManageBean.getFieldTypes()}"
                    var="value" itemLabel="#{value}" itemValue="#{value}" />
            </b:selectOneMenu>
            <br />
            <br />


            <h:inputTextarea id="itemArea" cols="30" rows="10" />


            <h:outputLabel for="color">Required:</h:outputLabel>
            <b:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{infoManageBean.field.required}">
            </b:selectBooleanCheckbox>


            <h:outputLabel for="color">Is active:</h:outputLabel>
            <b:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{infoManageBean.field.isActive}" />
            <input type="hidden" name="method" value=" ADD " />
            <b:commandButton look="primary" binding="#{infoManageBean.button}"
                id="addFieldBtn" validateClient="true"
                action="#{infoManageBean.insertOrUpdateField()}"></b:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleChange(selection) {
            var COMBO_BOX = 'COMBO_BOX';
            if (selection == COMBO_BOX) {
                console.log('visible');
                $('#itemArea').show();
            } else {
                console.log('hidden');
                $('#itemArea').hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF forms, by default, add a prefix to its children ids to look like this: "form-id:child-id", so jquery is not able to find the element using the selector "#child-id".

Use prependId="false" in the form:

```
<h:form style="margin: 0 auto" prependId="false">
```

Or define the id in the form:

```
<h:form style="margin: 0 auto" id="formId">
```

and use a different selector :

```
$('#formId\\:itemArea')
```

Comment: Great. The id prefix sounds crazy, but you will see that it is useful when you reuse components and fragments, because it helps to avoid ids collapsing